# Find and Replace XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, replace, find, itunes

I have an inaccurate podcast generator that I'm trying to correct using php with this code:

```
<?php
$superxmlfile_load_file("http://www.podcastgarden.com/podcast/podcast-rss.php?id=2337");
$xml= str_replace(type="audio/mp4", type="video/mp4", $superxmlfile);
echo $newtext
?>
```

Anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: you missed quotes `$xml= str_replace('type="audio/mp4"', 'type="video/mp4"', $superxmlfile);`

Comment: looks like a lot of syntax errors. what do you mean by `$superxmlfile_load_file`?

Comment: @Andrew The script has a blank output and error messages.

Comment: @bansi `$superxmlfile_load_file` was me trying to load an XML file and save it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lot of syntax errors.

Try this.

```
<?php
$superxmlfile = file_get_contents("http://www.podcastgarden.com/podcast/podcast-rss.php?id=2337");
$xml= str_replace('type="audio/mp4"', 'type="video/mp4"', $superxmlfile);
echo $xml;
?>
```

You should get at-least a basic editor with PHP code syntax highlight.

Comment: You missed the broken assignment to `$superxmlfile` and echoing out something that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that xml into something that you can manipulate.

First off, get the xml by using the proper function `simplexml_load_file()`.

Second, after getting the raw xml, convert it to an array. You can use `json_encode()` then `json_decode()` for that.

Third, since you already know what key value pair to exchange, just directly overwrite the current converted array.

Consider this example:

```
$url = 'http://www.podcastgarden.com/podcast/podcast-rss.php?id=2337';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$raw_data = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
$raw_data['channel']['item']['enclosure']['@attributes']['type'] = 'video/mp4';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($raw_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => Array
        (
            [title] => ACPG
            [link] => http://www.podcastgarden.com/podcast/acpg#2337
            [language] => en-us
            [copyright] => Mean Elephant Productions
            [description] => Broadcast live every month ACPG is definitely one of the best podcasts Owen has starred in.
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Episode 1
                    [enclosure] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => http://www.podcastgarden.com/login/audio-3/3550/ACPGEpisode1.mp4
                                    [type] => video/mp4 // <-- from audio/mp4
                                    [length] => 6000
                                )

                        )

                    [guid] => http://www.podcastgarden.com/episode/episode-1_9845
                    [pubDate] => Sat, 25 Jan 2014 00:00:00 MST
                )

        )

)
```